# Insert into bridge table entity framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-relationship, junction-table

**Hi guys**,
I'm learning to climb with EF ,I do have basic understanding of CRUD with EF ,but now I have a table which have a navigation property (Which I suspect is the bridge table) ,so I need to add value into the bridge table ,I think I can do it with navigational property.

**Problem Explained:**
*Original partial DB Diagram*
[image]

*Partial EF Model Diagram*
[image]

**Code I Wrote:**

```
   protected void BtnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBEntities entities = new DBEntities();
        var usr = new User();
        //I thought I would add an Roles object into usr.UserRoles.Add(usrRoles);
        //but UserRoles have only two fields ,RoleTypeId and UserId 
        //var usrRoles = new Roles() 
        //{Id=0,RoleDescription="dfdfdf",RoleType="WebSite Admin"}; 

        usr.UserName = TxtbxUserName.Text;
        usr.Password = TxtBxPassword.Text;
        usr.Email = TxtbxEmail.Text;
        usr.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        usr.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
        usr.IsEnabled = true;

        //What to Add in the .Add method
        usr.UserRoles.Add(

        entities.User.AddObject(usr);
        int result = entities.SaveChanges();
        LblMsg.Text = result == 1 ? "User created successfully." : "An error occured    ,please try later.";

        entities.Dispose();
    }
```

**Update (What I have tried so far):**
I fetch "Website Admin" role from roles table and put it into `ObjectContext.UserRoles.Add(UserRoleWebsiteAdmin);`
So that what I did in the code,

```
        //Fetch WebsiteAdmin from Roles
        var userRole = from usrRole in entities.Roles
                       where usrRole.Id == 1
                       select usrRole;

        usr.UserName = TxtbxUserName.Text;
        //same old code of usr.Property = someTextBox
        //I have tried to type cast it LinqtoEntities result into Roles
        usr.UserRoles.Add((Roles)userRole);
```

*Exception generated*
[image]

**P.S:** Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: What is `UserRoles`? You don't have such navigation property in your model described  by diagram. You just need to add `Role` to `Roles` property.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka 'UserRoles' is the bridge(or junction) table ,Upon user creation user must be given a role (or roles) ,which will be referenced from the 'Roles' table.

Comment: But that table is not in your model. You don't need it you just add `Role` to `user.Roles` and EF will handle it.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka A little code example would helpful for noobs like me :)

Comment: How about that, If I fetch "Website Admin" role from roles table and put it into like usr.UserRoles.Add(UserRoleWebsiteAdmin);

Comment: Look again at the entity picture you posted in your question - the one where you marked `Roles` property. Where is `UserRoles` in that picture?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka You are right its not there,then how do I insert into bridge table ,check my previous comment ,I think that will work.

Comment: Just try `usr.Roles.Add(UserRoleWebsiteAdmin)`

Comment: What he's saying is that Entity Framework will do this work for you because of the navigation properties which are showing up on your image. Because you have two FK in the mapping table, entity framework is smart enough to know what you're doing and just does it behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Ok wait just trying to do that :)

Comment: To your Update: `userRoles` is only a *query*, you need to *execute* it to get a role *entity*: `var userRole = (from usrRole ... select usrRole).Single();` for example.

Comment: You need to understand Many-to-Many relationship in EF http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-5/ and http://buildstarted.com/2010/08/27/entity-framework-with-many-to-many-one-to-many-and-one-to-one-relationships/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use `using` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx and  object initializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx for better readability so:

```
using(DBEntities entities = new DBEntities())
{
       //Make user object
       var user = new User{
            UserName = TxtbxUserName.Text,
            Password = TxtBxPassword.Text,
            Email = TxtbxEmail.Text,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now,
            IsEnabled = true
        };

       //Fetch type of Role from Roles table
       var userRole = entities.Roles.Where(x=>x.usrRole.Id ==1).Single();
       user.UserRoles.Add(userRole);

       entities.User.AddObject(user);
       int result = entities.SaveChanges();
       LblMsg.Text = result == 2 ? "User created succesfully." : "An error occured ,please try later.";
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I like it , +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks guys...
Here what I have done and it works,

```
       DBEntities entities = new DBEntities();
       //Make user object
       var usr = new User();
       //Fetch type of Role from Roles table
       var userRole = (from usrRole in entities.Roles
                       where usrRole.Id == 1
                       select usrRole).Single();
        //copy user related info from textboxes
        usr.UserName = TxtbxUserName.Text;
        usr.Password = TxtBxPassword.Text;
        usr.Email = TxtbxEmail.Text;
        usr.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        usr.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;
        usr.IsEnabled = true;


        usr.UserRoles.Add(userRole as Roles);

        entities.User.AddObject(usr);
        int result = entities.SaveChanges();
        LblMsg.Text = result == 2 ? "User created succesfully." : "An error occured ,please try later.";

        entities.Dispose();
```